# How do I dynamically query a JSON object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my Angular (v. 1.6.3) app, I've grabbed a JSON object full of stock price information. As you can see in the example below, because of its structure it can only be queried using brackets (each key is a string including spaces, parenthesis, periods, etc.):

```
{ "Time Series (Daily)":
    "2017-11-17":
      "4. close": "82.4000"
    "2017-11-18":
      "4. close": "79.2000"
}
```

In my controller, I've stored this JSON object as a variable (`$scope.stocks`), and have created what I thought would be a way to dynamically alter the data being displayed in my HTML:

```
$scope.thisStock = $scope.stocks["Time Series (Daily)"][$scope.currentDate]["4. close"];
```

`$scope.currentDate` dynamically alters based on form input from the HTML (ie, the user can slide a widget to select the current date from which to display this stock's closing price).

Here's the HTML, which ought to be dynamically displaying the closing stock price for whatever date the user has selected:

```
{{thisStock | currency}}
```

I have tested `$scope.currentDate` (it gives me a properly-formatted date string) and I have tested querying `$scope.stocks` statically (it works), but how can I make the HTML display dynamically? When I try with my current setup, it's not using `$scope.currentDate` as a variable -- it's seeing it as a string and thus telling me that my query is invalid.

I feel that I may be approaching this from the wrong angle somehow. Help!

Comment: If you find an answer please do mark as the answer for future users or add the answer yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch for changes in `currentDate`

try this

```
$scope.$watch('currentDate', function() {
  $scope.thisStock = $scope.stocks["Time Series (Daily)"][$scope.currentDate]["4. close"];
});
```